# How to auto-capitalize the label of a UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uilabel

I'm working with a designer and we have a few different typefaces involved in the project, sometimes doing everything in all caps, sometimes all lower case. This applies to both my labels and buttons. These may change, so what I'm attempting to do is have custom UILabel and UIButton classes where the button title will be automatically adjusted to the case I want without regards to what capitalization is entered in the interface builder or text from code. I have successfully managed this with my custom labels with the following code:

```swift
class MyHeadlineLabel : UILabel {
    override func didMoveToWindow() {
        self.text = self.text?.lowercased()
        self.font = MyFonts.headlineFont
    }
}
```

However, adding similar code to the `didMoveToWindow()` function of UIButton does NOT work:

```swift
class MyDarkTextButton: UIButton {
    override func didMoveToWindow() {
        self.titleLabel?.text = self.titleLabel?.text?.uppercased()
        self.font = MyFonts.subHeadFont            
    }
}
```

How would I go about doing that? Or, better yet, is there a way to use my custom labels as the button labels?

Comment: you can use UIView method `willMove(toSuperview:)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622629-willmove?changes=_4

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to set `title` of button, not `titleLabel`'s text directly. updated your code as follows:

```
override func didMoveToWindow() {
    self.setTitle(self.title(for: .normal)?.uppercased(), for: .normal)
}
```

This code is working for me, I hope this will help you.

Comment: If you are going to use `setTitle(_:for:)` to set the title, use `title(for:)` to get the title.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create separate Class just to make text Uppercase

```
/// Set Button Title
myButton.setTitle("myText".uppercased(), for: .normal)

/// Set Label Text
myLabel.text = "myText".uppercased()
```

Answer (score 0):

Easily done in Swift 5 through `updateConfiguration()` func.

You can implement your own button class and change the text to an uppercase text.

```
class MyButton: UIButton {
    override func updateConfiguration() {
        guard let updatedConfiguration = configuration else {
            return
        }

        updatedConfiguration.title = updatedConfiguration.title?.uppercased()
        
        self.configuration = updatedConfiguration
}
```

Then wherever you want a button that uppercases text, just set the class of the Storyboard button to this one.